# Convert Rowwise Data to Columnar Data MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a join query which give me out like below :

| rollNo | subject | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Maths | 90 |
| 1 | English | 80 |
| 1 | Science | 70 |
| 1 | Computer | 90 |

I want output like below:

| rollNo | Maths | English | Science | Computer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 | 80 | 70 | 90 |

Comment: Search for existing solutions using the term "PIVOT".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)